# Is the workaround to suppress the 404 warning of the HTML base tag?

Tags: html, django, angularjs

I have this `base` set in place.

```
<base href="/static/app/">
```

It works correctly -CSS, JS, Images references-, except that I get a pesky `404` error on the console. My app is not set to expose static directories, but I still don't get why my angular app would try to reach `/static/app/` when there's no use for it.

Comment: So what resource gives you 404?

Comment: `/static/app/` itself. It's like it's trying to reach my base dir for no reason at all.

Comment: not enough information given. Hard to follow how a page can load resources properly but page itself returns 404

Comment: @rebelliard did you manage to solve it?